# insertion sort does not order array correctly

Tags: python, algorithm, insertion-sort, insertion-order

Here is my insertion sort, exactly the way it is in the book "introduction to algorithms":

```
def insertion_sort():
    A = [5,2,4,6,1,3]
    for j in range(1, len(A)):
        print 'j:'+str(j)
        key = A[j]
        print 'key:'+str(key)
        i=j-1
        print 'i:'+str(i)
        while i > 0 and A[i] > key:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
            i=i-1
            print 'new i: '+str(i)
        print 'swapping value: '+str(A[i]) + ' with value: '+str(A[i+1])
        print ' '
        A[i+1] = key
    print A
```

This prints:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

What am I doing wrong to have them out of order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Introduction to Algorithms*, they always assume arrays start at index 1, so you are starting your `range()` at **1**, but python lists are 0-based indexed. This means you are never comparing `5`, which  is at `A[0]`. Notice everything after `5` is sorted.

modifying your for loop to -

```
for j in range(0, len(A)):
```

and your while condition to

```
while i >= 0 and A[i] > key:
```

Should do the trick.